# Pandas works in Python shell but not within Atom

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I would kindly ask for information please.
I am Windows 10 user.Installed Atom and Python 3.5. I am running my codes in Atom using script package. I have installed numpy, matplotlib, scipy and pandas separately (pip install xxx). I did not install Anaconda.

While other libaries work fine, pandas is giving me a headache. It appears that pandas works in Python shell but not in Atom or when I call the code written in Atom using command prompt. 
1) What seems to be the problem and how to resolve it?
2) If I decide to avoid manual libraries installations, shall I delete Python and related libraries (numpy etc) previously installed? Will I be still able to  run  Python within Atom. At this point, I am very comfortable using Atom.

Thanks

Comment: Run this code in either one and report what you get `import sys; sys.path`

Comment: Hi Thanks for prompt reply...This is what I get. The output is the same in Python shell and within Atom. Previously, I installed numpy package and works fine in both............'C:\\Users\\XXXX\\Desktop\\Learn\\v3', 'C:\\Users\\XXXXXX\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python35\\python35.zip', 'C:\\Users\\XXXXXXX\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python35\\DLLs', 'C:\\Users\\XXXXXXXX\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python35\\lib', 'C:\\Users\\XXXXXXX\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python35', 'C:\\Users\\XXXXXXXX\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python35\\lib\\site-packages']